# Is there an awk equivalent of INT_MIN and INT_MAX?

Tags: awk, gawk

In C and Java, there are defined constants representing the maximum and minimum values an integer can hold.

Are there such constants in `awk`? If so, what are their names?

The [awk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Arbitrary-Precision-Arithmetic) indicates that awk can support arbitrary precision integer arithmetic with `-M`, but I'd like to know about the bounds on integers when we do *not* specify `-M`.

Comment: It's implementation-defined (you'd have to write a test-program to determine the available precision).  By the way, that's the **`gawk`** manual.  For **awk** you have to go to POSIX.

Answer (score 6):

Not really something I've considered before so I may be barking up the wrong tree completely but since awk uses double-precision floating-point numbers by default, maybe what you're looking for is based on the value of `PREC` in gawk (see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Setting-precision). Look:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{print PREC}'
53

$ awk 'BEGIN{print (2^52)}'
4503599627370496
$ awk 'BEGIN{print (2^52)+1}'
4503599627370497

$ awk 'BEGIN{print (2^PREC)}'
9007199254740992
$ awk 'BEGIN{print (2^PREC)+1}'
9007199254740992
```

Notice how integer arithmetic fails when you try to go beyond `2^PREC`? So maybe `2^PREC` is a reasonable value to use for a MAX_INT equivalent and you could derive a MIN_INT similarly. Think about it, try it, see if it makes sense for your needs....

Answer (score 6):

High integers in current (`g`)`awk` are oddly broken without `-M`. It is easy to spot that `BEGIN {print 2^1024}` yields `inf`, whereas `BEGIN {print 2^1023}` works. One would therefore assume that the maximum integer in this particular implementation is 2<sup>1024</sup> − 1. Yet this is **not** the case.

A simple experiment, based on the fact that 2<sup>1024</sup> − 1 = 2<sup>1023</sup> + 2<sup>1022</sup> + ⋯ + 2<sup>1</sup> + 2<sup>0</sup>:

```
BEGIN {for (i = 1023; i >= 0; --i) sum += 2^i; print sum}
```

This^^^ yields infinity, surprisingly enough. So, at which point do we need to stop adding the powers of 2 in order to obtain a valid result? On my systems the limit appears to be 971 — try 970 and it sums to infinity.

```
BEGIN {for (i = 1023; i >= 971; --i) sum += 2^i; print sum}
```

This^^^ prints `179769313486231570814527423731704356798070567525844996598917476803157260780028538760589558632766878171540458953514382464234321326889464182768467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881250404026184124858368`.

The value has a surprising property in `awk`: Whatever you add to it, up to a certain number, does not change it any more. (Try to print (e.g.) `sum + 3`.) Incrementing it (although it appears to remain unchanged, based on the `print` output) beyond a certain threshold yields infinity, eventually. This is definitely a bug.

As for the original sum above (2<sup>1023</sup> + ⋯ + 2<sup>971</sup>), it is still correct in `awk`. Things start to fall apart once you try to increase that sum further. For example (and surprisingly), this still yields the same result as above:

```
BEGIN {for (i = 1023; i >= 971; --i) sum += 2^i
       for (i = 969; i >= 0; --i) sum += 2^i
       print sum}
```

Checking both sums with Python is easy:

```py
sum = 0

for i in range(971, 1024):
  sum += 2**i
print(sum)  # awk gets this right

for i in range(0, 970):
  sum += 2**i
print(sum)  # awk without -M gets this wrong
```

All in all, I think I will be setting `-M` in `awk` all the time from now on!

Comment: Good investigation.  At a glance, the surprising properties all probably make sense if you assume that variables are all floating point with double precision.  Note: `-M` or `--bignum` (https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Options.html) is likely specific to `gawk`.  Many distros (including Ubuntu) may default to other versions such as `mawk`.